# How to resolve flexbox formatting differences bewtween Firefox and Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, flexbox

I want to change the order of sidebar elements using a user style sheet (no access to change html or scripts).

I'm using Stylish CSS to add display: flex; to the container div and order: to the children to be moved and in FF it works perfectly but in Chrome the same CSS formats very differently.

I have reduced the problem to a single line

If I apply the style `.sidebar { display:flex; flex-direction: column;  }` to website http://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowForum-g1-i12105-TripAdvisor_Support.html I get the results I expect and want with Firefox (31.0): [image: FF format correct]

but with Chrome (36.0) the formatting is totally different: [image: Chrome format messed up]

Why are the two browsers handling the same page so differently? 
What needs to be done to get Chrome to format the same as Chrome?

Adding an explicit height: makes some difference in Chrome but each child div is still truncated and since I don't know the number or size of the child elements it is not a practical solution

Comment: Its because chrome has 1 more topic than firefox

Answer (score 0):

I found that one of the classes specified on the Sidebar child elements had for some, non obvious, reason a `height:100%;` property that FF appears to ignore for both flexbox and normal column formatting but which Chrome was using when the formatting the column for flexbox.

Changing to `height:auto;` for both the container and child elements seems to have resolved my problems and I am able to reorder the children as needed